# How to prevent VS designer from updating controls localized values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In my program I have a form that uses localized labels (from resx file). Unfortunately whenever I add a new control - designer is refreshing all the labels to their default values. 
Does anyone know how to prevent that from happening? 
Is there a better way of localizing forms or is creating a method that will replace all the labels on form load the only option?

Similar problem is posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637222/how-can-default-values-in-overridden-winform-controls-be-prevented) but this is obviously not the best solution for my issue.

P.S. I don't want to use forms localization property cause this gives me to little flexibility (or I'm just to dumb to use it :P). I don't like when to much things happens behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We try to localize our forms **after** the forms are almost done (from UI perspective)
Otherwise
We try to **avoid** the Visual Studio (VS 2005) designer for localizing, because of some bad experiences in the past.

Use a GREAT tool like the <s>[resx tool](http://www.papadi.gr/Default.aspx?TabId=290)</s> for translating your app. This tool is awesome!!