# Sub Classed controls not updating in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

sub classed controls that already exist on a winform are not updated when the sub classed control is updated :( 
This problem is evident whether in the designer or when the code is run.
Is there a way round this problem, as updating loads of controls by taking them of and putting new ones on seems a kludge?

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about custom controls drived from original controls? So you mean if you update the base class, derived classes are not updating?

Comment: Well, they are certainly updated, it won't keep a copy of the old one.  Which is the typical problem, it can't automatically remove, rename or edit properties that were assigned in the designer when it was used with the old version.  Getting a White Screen of Darn is not unusual.  Test first, use later.  Or edit the designer.cs file by hand.

Comment: Say the background of a sub classed textbox is grey you add the grey sub classed textbox a form from the toolbox. You then change your mind and change the sub classed textbox backgroud to red. You rebuild the project and when you look at the form the textbox is still grey! Any new new sub classed textbox is red.

Comment: That's getting the code wrong, the Background property should have never been serialized into the designer.cs file.  Use the [DefaultValue] attribute correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a question I originally had starting WinForms stuff and had similar problems...

[I resolved with the READONLY option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637222/how-can-default-values-in-overridden-winform-controls-be-prevented)

The first caveat...  Once you set a given property... font size, name, back color, fore color, etc to read only and compile your app, every form that has those controls in it, every control will nag at you about error trying to set a read-only property.  All you have to do is go through all the errors and remove the line(s) associated with these read-only properties.  However, if you are not too far into your app, it shouldn't take too long.

Once THAT is done, any time you change your "Read-only" element and re-open the form, the new values will take precedence over the old as the serialization of the designer will NOT put those values in.

Once you get those elements you want standardized / restricted, you are somewhat stuck (only somewhat).  Even though you may not have a property getter/setter for the property, you CAN still have a public METHOD (that the designer doesn't use), but in code, you CAN change the value such as...

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
   public MyTextBox() 
   {
      myBackColor = "Red";
   }

   private Color myBackColor

   [ReadOnly]
   public Color BackColor
   { get { return myBackColor; } }

   public void SetNewBackColor( Color anyNewColor )
   {
      myBackColor = anyNewColor;
   }
}
```

Finally, for those you have "cleaned up" from explicit content in the form's designer, but you don't want to LEAVE the elements as read-only, you can also use the attribute for 
[SerializableAttribute] and many others [you can find here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19191fh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  This won't explicitly include the serialized attribute unless you EXPLICITLY set it in the designer.

Hope this give you something good to chew on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    // Default all textboxes as string value instead of null
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public class MyTextbox : TextBox
    {
        // designer serialization is another alternative to preveting the IDE to analyze controls
        // at design time, but for other tighter controls, leave explicitly as READONLY...
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public override Font Font
        { get { return MyConstants.MyFontBase; } }

        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public override Color ForeColor
        { get { return Color.Red; } }

        [ReadOnly(true)]
        protected override Padding DefaultPadding
        { get { return MyConstants.MyPadding; } }

        // Now, on to the rest of the class definition and interaction if editing mode changed
        public MyTextbox()
        {
            base.Font = Font;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// constants used for common look / feel application wide for all controls
    /// such as textbox, label, buttons, comboboxes, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public class MyConstants
    {
        public static readonly Color MyColorBlue = Color.Blue;
        public static readonly Color MyFontForeColor = Color.Black;
        // public static readonly Color MyFontForeColorDisabled = Color.FromArgb(38, 146, 210);
        public static readonly Color MyFontForeColorDisabled = Color.Gray;
        public static readonly Color MyBackColorFieldRequired = Color.LightBlue;
        public static readonly Color MyBackColorFieldInvalid = Color.Red;
        public static readonly Color MyBackColorFieldNormal = Color.White;
        public static readonly String MyFontBaseName = "Arial";
        public static readonly float MyFontBaseSizeHdr = 16F;
        public static readonly float MyFontBaseSizeSubHdr = 11F;
        public static readonly float MyFontBaseSize = 14F;
        public static readonly Font MyFontBase = new Font(MyFontBaseName, MyFontBaseSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        public static readonly Font MyFontItalic = new Font(MyFontBaseName, MyFontBaseSize, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        public static readonly Size MyButtonSize = new Size(80, 25);
        public static readonly Padding MyPadding = new Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
    }

}
```

Above is some working code to show basis of working principles I've described.  I didn't have on my other machine from when I answered, but I was close...  The "MyConstants" is a static class so the object doesn't have to be instantiated, but in-turn, if you apply this concept to your base classes, then they can ALL have similar visual impact, features, colors, etc.

Comment: That is very interesting information. My goal is a control that can be changed in the custom subclass that updates all existing controls based on that class retrospectively in the designer. Your link is very informative but like much of MS information it is not backup by a coded example, as you have done.
Do you have any links to an example of how to do the above? Thanks

Comment: public partial class TestTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
         public TestTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           //this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            // now change it to red
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            // gray is still in the Designer file for all old controls so the above method is wrong
        } 
    }

Comment: @Hunt, sorry, I just pasted some snippets of production code that DOES what I described (from another machine).  I've stripped out a bunch of other stuff I had in it, but enough for you to chew on.  This one is based on a textbox, but could be applied to all types of controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the form in the designer and re-open it, it should update appropriately.  If I had to guess, I would think that VS is caching the control appearance to save on processing time.